# change Buttons Position in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help. I use woodmart handmade template, but when I go to the product page, I don't like the dimensions and the placement of the buttons like add to cart, buy, pay via google, apple pay.

I would need it to look like a mega electronics template. -

https://www.supermania.cz/produkt/amd-ryzen-5-7600x/

Could you please help me? I would be very grateful

My Page -

https://www.bestmoments.sk/?product=eames-lounge-chair

It is a page from the same company, according to which I would need to have buttons, google and apple pay, add to cart, buy. on the product side.

here is the page I would need it from -

https://www.supermania.cz/produkt/amd-ryzen-5-7600x/

I make the site on wordpress
I would be very grateful if someone could help me
I tried watching some YouTube videos but they didn't help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.